# Ошибка java: Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, swing, gui

Читаю книгу1 "Технологии java2",выполняю задания по текстовым компонентам swing и отображением HTML.Вообщем при компиляции программы в intellij idea

**вылетает ошибка:**
 ****Error:(16, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable browserPane
  location: class com.deitel.advjhtp1.gui.webbrowser.WebBrowser****

**и еще одна:**
Error:(34, 43) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method goToUrl(java.net.URL)
  location: variable webBrowserPane of type com.deitel.advjhtp1.gui.webbrowser.WebBrowserPane
**Вопрос:** Из перевода понятно что она не может найти какой-то символ,но какой?

**P.S** Книга просто супер и читается достаточно легко, но так и не понял до конца как с ней работать...И не уверен что код дописал до конца поэтому приложу еще  [часть первой главы](https://yadi.sk/d/KqZnecIw3CdACk) и скриншот ниже того что у меня есть.Буду очень признателен если кто-нибудь разъяснит как работать с книгами такого плана и что означает ошибка java: cannot find symbol
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта ошибка означает, что такой переменной не существует. Потому что поле у вас `webBrowserPane`, а пытаетесь вы использовать `browserPane`.

Либо `browserPane` замените везде на `webBrowserPane`, либо

```
private WebBrowserPane webBrowserPane;
```

на

```
private WebBrowserPane browserPane;
```

Если эта опечатка присутствует в книге - значит, это лишнее напоминание о том, что книги не идеальны (в них возможны ошибки и опечатки) и нужно следить за тем, что пишут. Если в книге ошибки нет - значит, вам нужно просто аккуратнее переписывать код с книги.

И в любом случае нужно внимательно смотреть на написанный вами код, а также обращать внимание на подсказки IDE. Например, в данном случае IDE подчеркивает `webBrowserPane` как неиспользуемое поле класса - это уже должно настораживать.